# Docker gitlab-ci runner immediately exits

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to register a gitlab-runner that is running within Docker as per https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html

```
docker run \
  -p 8093:8093 \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  --mount type=bind,source=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt,target=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt \
gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest register \
  --non-interactive \
  --executor shell \
  --url "$REGISTRATION_URL" \
  --registration-token "$REGISTRATION_TOKEN" \
  --limit "1" \
  --name "cumulus-runner" \
  --tls-ca-file="/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt" \
  --tag-list "cumulus"
```

When the container starts, the process exits immediately afterwards:

```
❯ docker run -p 8093:8093 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --mount type=bind,source=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt,target=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest register -n --executor shell -u "$REGISTRATION_URL" -r "$REGISTRATION_TOKEN" --limit "1" --name "cumulus-runner" --tls-ca-file="/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt" --tag-list "cumulus"                                                                                           Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=6 revision=7a6612da version=13.12.0
Running in system-mode.                            
                                                   
Registering runner... succeeded                     runner=jMkWoLVS
Runner registered successfully. Feel free to start it, but if it's running already the config should be automatically reloaded! 

❯ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                                                  COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                      PORTS                    NAMES
62febd5e7573   gitlab-runner:latest          "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   4 minutes ago    Exited (0) 4 minutes ago                             practical_shamir
```

When I run the command outside of docker, the `gitlab-runner` process is kept alive:

```
❯ ps aux | grep gitlab-         
root      1717  0.0  0.1 1904556 21200 ?       Ssl  Jun08   0:35 /usr/bin/gitlab-runner run --working-directory /var/lib/gitlab-runner --config /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml --service gitlab-runner --syslog --user gitlab-runner
```

Am I overlooking something? I feel like the container should be kept alive?

Answer (score 0):

In my test, I did not use `-p`

```sh
docker volume create gitlab-runner-config

docker run -d --name gitlab-runner --restart always \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    -v gitlab-runner-config:/etc/gitlab-runner \
    gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
```

or you can check the logs, what's the error?

```sh
docker logs gitlab-runner
```